# Python: Convert a list of python dictionaries to an array of JSON objects

Tags: python, json

I'm trying to write a function to convert a python list into a JSON array of {"mpn":"list_value"} objects, where "mpn" is the literal string value I need for every object but "list_value" is the value from the python list.  I'll use the output of this function for an API get request.

```
part_nums = ['ECA-1EHG102','CL05B103KB5NNNC','CC0402KRX5R8BB104']

def json_list(list):
    lst = []
    d = {}
    for pn in list:
        d['mpn']=pn
        lst.append(d)
    return json.dumps(lst, separators=(',',':'))

print json_list(part_nums)
```

This current function is not working and returns last value in the python list for all JSON objects:

```
>[{"mpn":"CC0402KRX5R8BB104"},{"mpn":"CC0402KRX5R8BB104"},{"mpn":"CC0402KRX5R8BB104"}]
```

However, of course I need my function to return the unique list values in the objects as such:

```
>[{"mpn":"ECA-1EHG102"},{"mpn":"CL05B103KB5NNNC"},{"mpn":"CC0402KRX5R8BB104"}]
```

Bottom line is I don't understand why this function isn't working. I expected I could append a dictionary with a single {key:value} pair to a python list and it wouldn't matter that all of the dictionaries have the same key because they would be independent. Thanks for your help.

Comment: move `d = {}` two lines down, inside the `for`

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You are adding the exact same dictionary to the list. You should create a new dictionary for each item in the list:

```
json.dumps([dict(mpn=pn) for pn in lst])
```

Comment: can we do a reverse of this ? converting a string which is array of json objects to dict ?

Comment: @divyenduz: the "reverse of this" is converting a json text that contains an array of json objects into *list* of dictionaries. Yes, we can: `list_of_dicts = json.loads(json_text)`. If something is unclear, [ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)

Answer (score 11):

As explained by others (in answers) you should create a new dictionary for each item on the list elsewhere you reference always the same dictionary

```
import json
part_nums = ['ECA-1EHG102','CL05B103KB5NNNC','CC0402KRX5R8BB104']

def json_list(list):
    lst = []
    for pn in list:
        d = {}
        d['mpn']=pn
        lst.append(d)
    return json.dumps(lst)

print json_list(part_nums)
```

print

```
[{"mpn": "ECA-1EHG102"}, {"mpn": "CL05B103KB5NNNC"}, {"mpn": "CC0402KRX5R8BB104"}]
```

Comment: Doh, thank you very much for the solution that match my original (inelegant) code. The one line solution is obviously better code but I appreciate you revealing my error.

Answer (score 0):

```
import json
part_nums = ['ECA-1EHG102','CL05B103KB5NNNC','CC0402KRX5R8BB104']

def json_list(list):
    lst = []
    for pn in list:
        d = {}
        d['mpn']=pn
        lst.append(d)
    return json.dumps(lst)

print json_list(part_nums)   # for pyhon2
print (json_list(part_nums)) # for python3
```