# How to create bulk JSON for Python requests payload?

Tags: python, json, api, dictionary, python-requests

I have a list of items that I want to add to the payload for a bulk API requests. I don't seem to be able to add the items to the payload JSON the right way.

This is what I want to do:

```
import json

fruits = ['apple','pear','banana']

headers = {
   'X-Api-Key': API_KEY,
   'Content-Type': 'application/json',
}
 
data = {
   "requests": [
       {
           "params": {
               "fruit": ["apple"]
           }
       },
       {
           "params": {
               "fruit": ["pear"]
           }
       }
       {
           "params": {
               "fruit": ["banana"]
           }
       }
   ]
}
json_responses = requests.post(
   'https://foo.bar/api/bulk',
   headers=headers,
   json=data
).json()
```

How do I add a new `params` item to the data payload for each item in my list?

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11312733/python-convert-a-list-of-python-dictionaries-to-an-array-of-json-objects) from a few years ago but if I try:

```
my_fruits = json.dumps([dict(fruit=f) for f in fruits])
```

And then insert it like this I get the error "Object of type set is not JSON serializable".

I'm sure it's because I'm doing something wrong when converting my list to a dictionary and then adding it wrongly but I'm a bit stuck.

EDIT: To clarify, the issue I'm stuck with is how to iterate through the list of fruits and automatically add a `param` for them in the `data` dictionary before the request is made.

Comment: I'm not getting any error with your code

Comment: Sorry - I didn't make this clear. I created the above code manually. I want to loop through a list of hundreds of items in a list and create a new `params` entry in `data` for every item in the list. I'm not sure how to do it automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The params are in a list. So to add another one you need to append to that list.

```py
paramsList = data.get("requests")

for item in fruits:
  paramsList.append(
    {
       "params" : {
          "fruit" : item,
        }
    }
  )
```

This should work. It loops through the fruits list and adds them to the `requests` list in the correct format.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that you only need a for loop to solve your problem. If you have problems formatting your data with json.dumps, just make your own dictionary and repeat the process for each "fruit".

```
fruits   = ["a","b"]
requests = []

for f in fruits:
    requests.append({
        "params": { "fruit": [f] }
    })

data = { "requests": requests }
```

With these lines i got the following result when printing **data**:
`{'requests': [{'params': {'fruit': ['a']}}, {'params': {'fruit': ['b']}}]}`

Hope it solves the issue!

Comment: Thank you Lucas - this was just what I needed. I knew it would be something obvious but I didn't see what.